# Find most common words in sql

Tags: java, sql

I have a new problem. I have a database with a column that contains a wide variety of text, is there any way I can get SQL to tell me which are the 10 most common words used in these fields? As an example:

1 I am coming home a bit late today. 
2 Train is running late. 
3 What is the train schedule like today? 
4 Snow is really bad right now.

And output optimally would be:

is: 3 
late : 2 
train: 2 
today: 2

If it is not possible to do it with SQL, what else would you suggest I look into to get this information?

Comment: which server side language you are using

Comment: @ShehzadBilal OP is looking for an SQL solution.

Comment: Will your database only contain English sentences/phrases?

Comment: @ShehzadBilal OK posting re-tagged.

Answer (score 3):

This might technically be doable in SQL, but it will be painful and very slow when you have more rows in your database.

The problem you are describing is a perfect use case for an indexing engine though, such as [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) (I used this one as an example it since your question first contained the tag 'java' before being edited).

Comment: i want it..like twitter...TRENDING if you ever saw..it....the most talking about word come 1st...so what is the best solution for it?

Comment: @SanjayMewada: Using an indexing engine, that will index all the rows in the database. You can then query the indexing engine to obtain a list of the most used terms.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use table-valued split function that returns each word as a row ; count them ; sort them by count in descending order

Comment: i want it..like twitter...TRENDING if you ever saw..it....the most talking about word come 1st...so what is the best solution for it?